# NPM package has outdated dependency, is there a way to alter its version?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Just migrated to Node 4.1.2 from 0.10. One of the packages being installed via `npm install` errors due to node-gyp having a problem with one of its dependencies, it's quite a few versions out of date. The issue has been brought up on the repo but hasn't seen activity since May. Is there a way to tell NPM to install this package but with the outdated dependency using a newer version?

EDIT:
I've copied over an installed version from node_modules in an older project. `npm install -g npm-check-updates` then `ncu` in the `node_modules/bs-html-injector/` directory. It lists updates, `ncu -u` will update the package.json, `npm install` after. I run my gulp task and html is injecting fine, all seems fine :) Would still like to know how to do this if I didn't have a local copy installed by NPM. It looks like it's just a 1:1 copy from the github repo?

Comment: I'm not sure how to target it via NPM though? Have not published a package before and only ever used npm in CLI pointing to the package name.

Comment: Just fork the repo. Then edit it to change the dependency. Then include the forked repo in your project. npm will then do the right things.

Comment: @Brennan npm lets you install packages from GitHub directly: `npm install user/repo#branch`. You can use your fork on GitHub this way until PR is merged. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: @eush77 Cheers, for the command and doc link. Feel free to make that an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With npm, you [can install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) packages from GitHub directly:

```
npm install user/repo#branch
```

You can fork the package on GitHub, make and propose the changes you need and use your fork as a dependency in your project until PR is merged.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `--force`  to force install it